# When using kpfonts, the vector versions of i and j don't behave nice with the physics package

Tags: vector, physics, kpfonts

When attempting to typeset unit vectors with the physics package shorthand `\vu` the following problems occur when using kpfonts which do not occur when using computer modern.

1. `\vu{i}` and `\vu{j}` do not use dotless versions of i and j.
2. When explicitly stating `\vu{\imath}` and `\vu{\jmath}`, the produced output is not in boldface, like every other character.
3. When working around the issue using `\hat{\textbf{\j}}`, the output (just for j) still has a dot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I try

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}

$\vu{i}+\vu{j}$

\end{document}
```

(note that `kpfonts` is commented out), I get

[image]

The dots are there and it's not surprising, because the package does

```
% Unit vector [star for Greek and italic Roman]
\DeclareDocumentCommand\vectorunit{ s m }{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\boldsymbol{\hat{#2}}}
    {\mathbf{\hat{#2}}}%
}
% Shorthand for \vectorunit
\DeclareDocumentCommand\vu{}{\vectorunit}
```

(reformatted for clarity).

Here's a way out (not only for `kpfonts`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{physics}

\makeatletter
\ifkp@sfmath
  \DeclareSymbolFont{boldletters}{OT1}{jkpss\kp@fligm\kp@stylem}{b}{n}
  \SetSymbolFont{boldletters}{bold}{OT1}{jkpss\kp@fligm\kp@stylem}{b}{n}
\else
  \DeclareSymbolFont{boldletters}{OT1}{jkp\kp@famillem\kp@fligm\kp@stylem}{b}{n}
  \SetSymbolFont{boldletters}{bold}{OT1}{jkp\kp@famillem\kp@fligm\kp@stylem}{b}{n}
\fi
\SetSymbolFont{boldletters}{rm}{OT1}{jkp\kp@famillem\kp@fligm\kp@stylem}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{boldletters}{boldrm}{OT1}{jkp\kp@famillem\kp@fligm\kp@stylem}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{boldletters}{sf}{OT1}{jkpss\kp@fligm\kp@stylem}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{boldletters}{boldsf}{OT1}{jkpss\kp@fligm\kp@stylem}{b}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbf}{boldletters}
\makeatother
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bi}{\mathord}{boldletters}{"10}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bj}{\mathord}{boldletters}{"11}

\begin{document}

$\vu{\bi}+\vu{\bj}$

\textbf{i j \^{\i} \^{\j}}

i j

\end{document}
```

[image]

A “self-fixing" approach, so you can input `\vu{i}` and `\vu{j}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{physics}

\makeatletter
\ifkp@sfmath
  \DeclareSymbolFont{boldletters}{OT1}{jkpss\kp@fligm\kp@stylem}{b}{n}
  \SetSymbolFont{boldletters}{bold}{OT1}{jkpss\kp@fligm\kp@stylem}{b}{n}
\else
  \DeclareSymbolFont{boldletters}{OT1}{jkp\kp@famillem\kp@fligm\kp@stylem}{b}{n}
  \SetSymbolFont{boldletters}{bold}{OT1}{jkp\kp@famillem\kp@fligm\kp@stylem}{b}{n}
\fi
\SetSymbolFont{boldletters}{rm}{OT1}{jkp\kp@famillem\kp@fligm\kp@stylem}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{boldletters}{boldrm}{OT1}{jkp\kp@famillem\kp@fligm\kp@stylem}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{boldletters}{sf}{OT1}{jkpss\kp@fligm\kp@stylem}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{boldletters}{boldsf}{OT1}{jkpss\kp@fligm\kp@stylem}{b}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbf}{boldletters}
\makeatother
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bi}{\mathord}{boldletters}{"10}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bj}{\mathord}{boldletters}{"11}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand\vectorunit{ s m }
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\boldsymbol{\hat{#2}}}
    {\mathbf{\hat{\fixphysics_replace:n{#2}}}}
 }
\cs_new:Nn \fixphysics_replace:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    { i } { \bi }
    { j } { \bj }
   }
   { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\vu{i}+\vu{j}$

\textbf{i j \^{\i} \^{\j}}

i j

\end{document}
```

Comment: Strangely enough, whatever combination of fonts and packages I was using before I moved to kpfonts had no dots on the is and js with `\vu{i}`.  I will definitely use this though.  Thanks!

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity I added a “self-fixing” approach.

Comment: Thanks for the self-fixing approach.  I have found it good practice to just add shortcut commands for things like this so that I can change them all by editing only one place.  In this case, I'm using `\ihat`, `\jhat`, and `\khat`, so it's not a big deal for me.  However, the technique I'm sure will be useful for other things :D

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity Oh, and don't use `physics`.

Answer (score 0):

While `\j` does have a dot, is it outside of the character boundary, so all one must do is explicitly clip to the font bounding box.

```
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{trimclip}
\usepackage{physics}

% HACK: \imath and \jmath don't go bold in the \vu environment, so use text mode instead
\newcommand{\ihat}{\, \hat{\textbf{\i}}}
% HACK: \j still has a dot, but it's defined outside of the bounding box for the character. Explicitly clip so it doesn't display.
\newcommand{\jhat}{\, \hat{\textbf{\clipbox{0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt}{\j}}}}
```